# java - appengnie code to get child entity from datastore not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i have this code to check if a child entity already exists in datastore. The problem is that it works for one parent-child relation but always returns null for another relation.

i have four kind of entities in my app - ORG, Contact, Profile, ProfileOrg. Contact kind entities are children of ORG and ProfileOrg are children of Profile. The logic to add a contact to ORG is to get all childentities for the given org and then check for a property. if property matches i return the entity else null. this works perfectly for ORG-Contact relation. but the exact same logic for Profile-ProfileOrg relation doesnot work. it always returns null. Below is my code:

This is the code to get all childentities and check if its property "orgID" matches or not.

```
public static Entity getSingleProfileOrg(Key profileKey, String orgID) {

    Iterable<Entity> childProfileOrgs = Util.listChildren("profileOrg",profileKey);

    for (Entity e : childProfileOrgs) {
        if (e.getProperty("orgID").toString() == orgID) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is the code to query datastore.

```
public static Iterable<Entity> listChildren(String kind, Key ancestor) {
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Search entities based on parent");
  Query query = new Query(kind);
  query.setAncestor(ancestor);
  query.addFilter(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN, ancestor);
  PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);
  return pq.asIterable();
}
```

Please help. this has got me stuck.

Edit: Code for getting ChildEntities for org which works perfectly

```
public static Entity getSingleContact(Key orgKey, String phoneContactID) {
    Iterable<Entity> childContacts = Util.listChildren("contact", orgKey);


    for (Entity e : childContacts) {
        if (e.getProperty("contactID") == phoneContactID) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Edit: Code to create or update ProfileOrg

```
public static void createOrUpdateProfileOrg(String profileID,
        String orgName, String ownerID) {
    String orgID = ownerID + "_" + orgName;
    Entity Profile = Product.getProfile(profileID);
    //Key profileKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Profile", profileID);
    Key profileKey = Profile.getKey();
    Entity profileOrg = getSingleProfileOrg(profileKey, orgID);
    if (profileOrg == null) {
        profileOrg = new Entity("profileOrg", profileKey);
        profileOrg.setProperty("name", orgName);
        profileOrg.setProperty("orgID", orgID);
        profileOrg.setProperty("owner", ownerID);
        profileOrg.setProperty("profileID", profileID);
        Util.persistEntity(profileOrg);
    }

}
```

the line

```
Entity Profile = Product.getProfile(profileID);
```

should be working fine as it is used to create profiles also and i dont see any problem there.

As i always get a null from getSingleProfileOrg(profileKey, orgID); i end up getting duplicate child entities.

Answer (score 1):

Since in `listChildren`, you want to query based an ancestor, your method is wrong. It should be like this:

```
public static Iterable<Entity> listChildren(String kind, Key ancestor) {
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Search entities based on parent");
  Query query = new Query(kind);
  query.setAncestor(ancestor);
  PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(query);
  return pq.asIterable();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i checked, still the same. That does not work.:(

I dont understand why it works for one kind of entity and not for the other when the code logic is exactly the same.

Comment: Can you add the code that you specify your model? Since probably there is something fishy there...

Comment: I am very new to this and the code is just from an example that i have modified. i don understand what u mean by a model. I am adding the other method that is used to create or update the profileOrg.

Comment: By model I mean the class that you are trying to query with this method. Since the query is correct, probably the problem lies in the way you construct the class.

Comment: No Thanos. That did not work. I was using the profileOrg to reduce the search time for the database, but i came to know that i have a limit on the number of datastore writes. so i have skip this idea now.

Thanks for your help.